# Objects mesh set to smooth but some edges show sharp after using Bevel tool

Tags: mesh

Please help me solve that. See images below.
[image: My mesh with edges selected]

[image]

As you see after I use Bevel tool, red circled edges are sharp. EdgeSplit modifier angle is 45 degrees, mesh set to smooth, no duplicate vertices.

Please help! Tried many ways but no luck. :-(

This is what I am trying to model.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *Bevel Modifier* with a *Limit Method* set to **Angle**, instead of Bevel tool + EdgeSplit modifier. *EdgeSplit modifier* only change wich Edge appear smoothed whereas *Bevel Modifier* allow to adjust wich Edge is beveled.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did not work for me as I need only selected edges to be beveled. Bevel Modifier add bevels to all edges.

Comment: @Andrzej Can you share your file or a beveled mesh view ? The mesh has N-gons ? Also I don't get the point of beveling all selected edges, specially  horizontal ones.

Comment: Sure here is a link. Selected edges come from the part of the aircraft cockpit that I am trying to model. Here is the link to GD     https://drive.google.com/open?id=16mMZVnEI0tBUXqIKbQ_Z46HK6hNYfXKP

Comment: Added image in original post to show what I am trying to model

Answer (score 0):

Both Bevel methods did not lead to great results, so you may use Subdvision modeling method:

1. Correct the topology to keep only quads. Disolve Edges (<kbd>x</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*), add new ones with the Knife Tool <kbd>K</kbd>.
   [image: Topology corrected]
2. Add holding edges using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
   [image]
3. Add a Subsurface Modifier
   [image]

[Topology Guides](http://topologyguides.com/post/153741336695/modeling-grip-ridges) has great step by step guide to solve similar topology. 
Final result is smooth:[image]
[Final Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EnnGlO68NCan6pS8yfNxdNlQnvyIKB31/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you, that looks pretty good except of one area, top left edge